# How to preserve script tags order on Vite build

Tags: vite

How to preserve the initial script tags order on Vite build ?

In my index.html head tag :

```
<script src="js/initMap.js" type="module"></script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/"></script>
```

In my build :

```
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/"></script>
<script src="js/initMap.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: I would think the order doesn't matter because `defer` makes sure it only executes when the other scripts are loaded?